# Problems with deleting user

Tags: command-line, bash, process, user-management, kill

I have problems with deleting a user on my Ubuntu terminal.
I log in as root and type:

```
# deluser mn1 
userdel: user mn1 is currently used by process 21106
/usr/sbin/deluser: `/usr/sbin/userdel mn1' returned error code 8. Exiting.
```

But I get the same error after:

```
# kill 21106
# deluser mn1
```

So I look what's going on with `top -u mn1` and I get:

```
21106 mn1       20   0   24772      0      0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.02 bash
```

What to do?

Comment: have you logged in to bash as user mn1 and changed without doing an `exit` or so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the default `kill` command doesn't work, try it with the `-9` option (as `root`):

```
sudo kill -9 21106
```

---

More info about `kill` can be found in: [man kill](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/kill.1.html)

The `-9` option means `SIGKILL` (see below table taken from [man signal](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man7/signal.7.html) for details)

```
Signal     Value     Action   Comment
──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
SIGHUP        1       Term    Hangup detected on controlling terminal
                              or death of controlling process
SIGINT        2       Term    Interrupt from keyboard
SIGQUIT       3       Core    Quit from keyboard
SIGILL        4       Core    Illegal Instruction
SIGABRT       6       Core    Abort signal from abort(3)
SIGFPE        8       Core    Floating point exception
SIGKILL       9       Term    Kill signal
```

Comment: Thnx it worked :)